# bootstrap rails and an autoloading issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in a rails application, without the gem but just including the relevant files. 
However, i want to copy some of the scaffolding created by the gem, just not to forget anything. Flash messages are managed by this line inside the layout:

```
<%= bootstrap_flash %>
```

that refers to a ruby file whose content you can find below. 
The problem is that whatever directory i put it in, I always get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `bootstrap_flash' for ...
```

What is going wrong here?

```
module BootstrapFlashHelper
ALERT_TYPES = [:error, :info, :success, :warning]

def bootstrap_flash
  flash_messages = []
  flash.each do |type, message|
    # Skip empty messages, e.g. for devise messages set to nothing in a locale file.
    next if message.blank?

    type = :success if type == :notice
    type = :error   if type == :alert
    next unless ALERT_TYPES.include?(type)

    Array(message).each do |msg|
      text = content_tag(:div,
                       content_tag(:button, raw("&times;"), :class => "close", "data-dismiss" => "alert") +
                           msg.html_safe, :class => "alert fade in alert-#{type}")
      flash_messages << text if msg
    end
  end
  flash_messages.join("\n").html_safe
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name of helper module is `BootstrapFlashHelper`, you should name the file as `bootstrap_flash_helper.rb` (in `snake_case`) and place it in `your_application/app/helpers` directory.

Now you can use the `bootstrap_flash` helper method in any of your views located in `your_application/app/views`. Make sure to restart the server after these changes.